# Trouble displaying image in mPDF on live server

Tags: php, codeigniter-3, mpdf

I'm having trouble displaying images using mpdf. 
I'm able to successfully display it using my local Xampp server. 
However on my live server the pdf display but it will not load the image part. The strange thing is that there is no red X indicator letting me know that there is an issue displaying an image either. I tried showImageErrors but this does not show anything.

I assume it must be some kind of server configuration issue however I already checked to make sure mbstring, zlib, and gd is installed and working.

This is the code I'm using to display the pdf.

```
$html = '<h1>Hello world</h1><img src="/assets/images/check.png" />';
$pdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf( [
    'tempDir' => __DIR__ . '/pdf_tmp',
    'debug' => true,
    'showImageErrors' => true,
    'allow_output_buffering' => true
]);
$pdf->WriteHTML($html);
$pdf->Output("Hello.pdf","I");
```

Everything about this works as should in Xampp, but for some crazy reason I cannot get the image to show in my live server. The text "Hello world" displays so I know the pdf if being generated but with no image. No red X. It's like the image doesn't exist.

Local and live is using same php7.1 and I'm using mdpf 7 as well.
Are there any other requirements for mpdf that may be causing this?

I should also mention that if I try to add a watermark image, this works fine.

```
$pdf->SetWatermarkImage('assets/images/watermark.png');
$pdf->showWatermarkImage = true;
$pdf->watermarkImageAlpha = 0.7;
$pdf->watermarkImgBehind = true;
```

so images do load this way.

Answer (score 0):

My bad, I resolved this by reinstalling all the mpdf files. The initial upload must of been incomplete or corrupted somehow.